# The UI for configuring auto scalling policy is confusing me

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

Very confused about what I'm seeing in the console.

1. I create an alarm for >=81% CPU
2. I select that alarm for a step policy
3. Set number of instances I want to scale on

Now I think im done here, but what I see in the UI is confusing:
[image]

First it automatically plugs in 81 for me under "when", BUT looks like I can change it to whatever I want? I type in 123 instead. Does this mean I can override the lower bound in my alarm? What purpose does that server? Is that like a quick manual override if I need to slow it down or change it quickly?

Also, what is that `< +infinity` about?

Edit: from experimenting with the UI I found "The lower bound of the first step must be greater than or equal to the alarm threshold"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The +infinity is just a label indicating the upper bound.
The actions can be step based.

That means you can create a policy based on your CPU utilisation. If you have an increased load, and CPU utilisation hits 80%, we want to add 8 instances, but if CPU utilisation is 60 - 70%, only add 2 instances.

See this release post for more info: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/auto-scaling-update-new-scaling-policies-for-more-responsive-scaling/

[image: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/auto-scaling-update-new-scaling-policies-for-more-responsive-scaling/]